# Waiting for `Image` to render in Flutter test

Tags: flutter

I wrote a little helper function that waits until an image is actually rendered in a flutter test:

```
Future<void> waitUntilImageRendered(WidgetTester tester, Finder finder) async {
  while (true) {
    final image = tester.renderObject<RenderImage>(finder);
    if (image.image != null) {
      break;
    }
    await tester.runAsync(() => Future<void>.delayed(Duration.zero));
    await tester.pump();
  }
}
```

However, I feel that this line `await tester.runAsync(() => Future<void>.delayed(Duration.zero));`  is a bit too violent since the whole thing might busy loop a bit when it takes more time to decode the image.

Is there a way to actually wait until a frame was scheduled and then call pump?